# What does (!started) inside conditional do in this context?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

```
$(document).keypress(function() {
  if (!started) {
    $("#level-title").text("Level " + level);
    nextSequence();
    started = true;
  }
});
```

I don't understand what does `(!started)` do inside the if condition.

Comment: Checks if it is not started. Check out [this page on logical NOT operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT) as well.

Comment: It's essentially equivalent to `if (started == false)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `started` is a Boolean variable (contains `true` or `false`) that represents the state of something that could be started or stopped, then the Statement,

```
if (!started) {
```

is asking IF NOT STARTED THEN... ELSE...

`!` represents the Not Operator and `started` represents the variable. This is a logical condition where `started` can be `true` or `false`. If `started` is `true`, then `!started` is `false`. If `started` is `false` then `!started` is `true`.

Here is another way the Not Operator can be used.

```
var started = true;
started = !started;
console.log(started); // false
```